# why are airplane propellers always undersized?

Tags: propeller, performance-calculation, pitch

While calculating propeller static thrust by using a famous [Prop-power-calculator.xls](http://www.fmfk.dk/Prop-power-calculator.xls) (by Pé Reivers),
I've noticed that no matter what "stock" configuration I put into the calculator, I do always get the propeller power required half or third of the engine power available.

I.e.:

- Zivko Edge 540: Lycoming AEIO-540-EXP 300HP@2700rpm engine, HARTZELL
  76" prop @ 11.5" pitch
  Calculator given performance: **51HP, 154Kg thrust**
- Piper Sport: Rotax 912ULS 100HP@2400rpm engine, Woodcompo 67" prop @ 
  10" pitch
  Calculator given performance: **17HP, 88Kg thrust**

[image]

**!NOTE** - calculator is for 2-blade props, while above planes have 3-blade props. However, that doesn't change the mismaching in numbers a lot.

Above engine RPM's are with reduction applied (i.e. 1:2.43). That means the actual HP available is two-fold!.

I would imagine everything shouldbe the other-way around(?)

- Reduction rates of 1:0.5, RPM's * 2, engine power / 2
- Or propeller driven directly by the shaft
- Or prop diameter increased (not to practical perhaps)
- Or pitch inreased
- Or number of blades increased?
- Or all of above?

What am I missing here?

Comment: 300hp = 223,710 watts, where did you get 38,216 from? It should also be noted that the worksheet you are using is meant for use on R/C airplanes...

Comment: Another possible explanation is that the engine are less effective with altitude, so the power at sea level may be greater than the power at the ceiling altitude.

Comment: Ron, that's exactly my point. Particular prop @ particular pitch @ particular RPM gives that much of a static thrust. Why are the engines scaled up if prop is technically unable to push for more?
I dare to disagree that the math behind the static thrust calculation differs for RC or True airplanes.

Comment: I'm not talking about thrust, at the point you enter the engine power in watts, you are off by a factor of almost 6. Edit: Ok, I see you can't enter the engine power there, but where do you enter engine details at all? I can't find that.

Comment: [This site](http://www.csgnetwork.com/directhpthrustcalc.html) calculates the 11.5 inch pitch, 2800 RPM, 300hp engine combo to deliver about 3690lbs of thrust, which is much more realistic.

Comment: @RonBeyer - the Zivko Edge 540 weighs 1,170 lbs.  A thrust to weight ratio of over 3:1 seems unlikely. Am I missing something?

Comment: @DanPichelman I'm not sure, possibly. I can't find a reliable source for the formula's to verify. The Edge 540 has a power:weight ratio of .21hp/lb. So if the propeller can generate 3lbs of thrust with .21hp, then it is realistic...

Comment: @DanPichelman, the problem is that for propeller, the engine provides (roughly) constant power, and power is thrust times speed. So statically, perhaps. At any reasonable speed, definitely not (it could provide 1 lbf around 50 knots, which is about right as the plane can climb vertically).

Comment: Anyway, if it is for R/C airplanes, there are likely some experimental factors that are simply way too different from corresponding values at full-scale.